# Hashicorp Vault docker networking issue

Tags: docker, hashicorp-vault

When setting up on a brand new EC2 server as a test I run the following and it all works fine.

```
/vault/config/local.json
{
        "listener": [{
                "tcp": {
                        "address": "0.0.0.0:8200",
                        "tls_disable": 1
                }
        }],
        "storage": {
                "file": {
                        "path": "/vault/data"
                }
        },
        "max_lease_ttl": "10h",
        "default_lease_ttl": "10h",
        "ui": true
}
docker run -d -p 8200:8200 -v /home/ec2-user/vault:/vault --cap-add=IPC_LOCK vault server
export VAULT_ADDR='http://0.0.0.0:8200'
vault operator init
```

I unseal and login fine.

On one of our corporate test servers I use 0.0.0.0 and I get a web server busy sorry page on the init. However, if I export 127.0.0.1 the init works fine. I cannot access the container from the server command line with a curl with 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1. I'm unsure why the behaviours are different?

I understand that 127.0.0.1 should not work but why am I get server busy on 0.0.0.0 on one server and not another in the actual container?

Thanks Mark

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is a special IPv4 address that means "everywhere"; it doesn't really make sense to use it when making outbound connections (like `$VAULT_ADDR`).

Comment: I'm not sure if you have resolved your issue or not, but have you had a chance to verify that Vault has started up correctly by inspecting the container logs? In addition, having a docker container bind to 0.0.0.0 will likely require you to access the Vault HTTP API via the dockers IP address which can be access with "docker describe"

Answer (score 0):

The listener works fine in the container with 0.0.0.0. To access the container externally you need to VAULT_ADDR to an address the server understands not the container.